# Robolectric Testing activity with dagger2

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd, dagger-2, robolectric

I have a activity that extend `DaggerAppCompatActivity` to enable injections on it using new dagger android injection tools

I'm trying test this activity using Robolectric but the test throws

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
```

How to disable dagger 2 injection to test the activity as normal activity

the test code

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class RegisterActivityTest {

    AppCompatActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setupActivity() {
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(RegisterActivity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void clickingNewAccountText_MakeNewAccountShouldBeVisible() {
        TextView registerNewAccountTextView = activity.findViewById(R.id.register_sign_up_textView);
        registerNewAccountTextView.performClick();

        Button registerNewAccountButton = activity.findViewById(R.id.register_sign_up_button);
        assertThat(registerNewAccountButton.getVisibility(), is(View.VISIBLE));
    }

}
```

any idea how to solve this problem

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am looking for something similar.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky  unfortunately not :( if you have found a solution please inform me

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem earlier.  The error you posted appears to indicate that your activity is calling AndroidInjection.inject(this).

Are you defining your own Application class that implements HasActivityInjector?

According to [Robolectric's documentation](http://robolectric.org/configuring/)

> Robolectric will attempt to create an instance of your Application
>   class as specified in the manifest

In my case what worked was configuring the unit tests to include the Android resources:

```
testOptions{
    unitTests{
        includeAndroidResources true
    }
}
```

in my module build.gradle, under the android{} section.